# How to keep a database updated from a xml file

Tags: java, mysql, sql, dom, jdbc

I'm trying to make a function that updates the database from a xml file. My collumns in the database - table: 'offers' : id(A_I,PK), city, country, hotel, description, price, image

I though that i will update an offer only if the city, country and hotel are the same. Else i will insert a new line.  I implemented first the reading of the xml file which works ok. The db connection is ok, i tested it.

I have 2 questions : First, if i can make this smaller. Second why doesn't work and says:

```
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
```

I believe that is a problem with the sql statement, but i can't tell how to solve it.
 My code so far:

```
package bookings1;
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory; 

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class addOffers implements Runnable {

    public void run(){
        Connection connection = null;
        connection = ConnectionConfiguration.getConnection();
        try {
             // Start getting offers from xml
            File fXmlFile = new File("c:\\offers.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);        
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();        
            System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());       
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("offers");         
            System.out.println("----------------------------");      
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {       
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);       
                System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());         
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {      
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;      
                    String DCity = eElement.getElementsByTagName("city").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String DCountry = eElement.getElementsByTagName("country").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String DHotel = eElement.getElementsByTagName("hotel").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String DDescription= eElement.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String DPrice = eElement.getElementsByTagName("price").item(0).getTextContent();
                    String DImage = eElement.getElementsByTagName("image").item(0).getTextContent();                    
                    PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE city=? AND country=? AND hotel=?");
                    st.setString(1, DCity);
                    st.setString(2, DCountry); 
                    st.setString(3, DHotel);  
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

                    if(rs.next()) { 
                     int theid = rs.getInt("id");   
                     PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
                                connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE offers SET description=?, price=?, image=? WHERE id=?");
                                preparedStatement.setString(1, DDescription);
                                preparedStatement.setString(2, DPrice); 
                                preparedStatement.setString(3, DImage);  
                                preparedStatement.setInt(4, theid);  
                                preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    }
                    else {
                        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
                        connection.prepareStatement("INSERT into orders (city, country, hotel, description, image, phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");                       
                            preparedStatement.setString(1, DCity);
                            preparedStatement.setString(2, DCountry); 
                            preparedStatement.setString(3, DHotel);  
                            preparedStatement.setString(4, DDescription);  
                            preparedStatement.setString(5, DPrice);
                            preparedStatement.setString(6, DImage);
                            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
                    }

                    connection.close();

                }
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Fetching from xml thread interrupted! " + e.getMessage());
          }


    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with JDBC comes a lot of boiler plate code.  Its never going to be short!  Try looking at JPA and Hibernate for your database functionality?

Secondly, your error message is telling you that you are trying to insert a parameter when there are none defined.

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE city='Beijing'");
st.setString(1, DCity);
st.setString(2, DCountry); 
st.setString(3, DHotel);
```

Basically, if you want to insert the three parameters into your prepared statement, it should look something like this:

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE city=? AND country=? AND hotel=?");
st.setString(1, DCity);
st.setString(2, DCountry); 
st.setString(3, DHotel);
```

Hope that makes things clearer for you!

Comment: I tryed it this too, please see the edited questions. Didn't work.

Comment: would it be possible to see the full stack trace?

Comment: Hi Alex, in your answer im not convinced you have resolved your original question.  While the code may now work, the two solutions you have documented are equivalent and should both provide the same result.  The fact that the PreparedStatement didnt work indicates there is another underlying problem in your code which you have failed to understand.  Also, I didnt understand what this means, "The problem was that in my execute query i had no parameter to save the data in the rs variable", it looked fine to me, please could you clarify. (Id comment on your own answer but I dont have the rep yet)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've used. :

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM offers where city='"+DCity + "' AND country='"+DCountry+"' AND hotel='"+DHotel+"'"; 
 Statement stmp = connection.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs = stmp.executeQuery(sql);
```

instead of

```
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM offers WHERE city=? AND country=? AND hotel=?");
st.setString(1, DCity); 
st.setString(2, DCountry); 
st.setString(3, DHotel);  
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

And now it works. The problem was that in my execute query i had no parameter to save the data in the rs variable.